# How to pass Env variables set in Travis CI inside the dockerfile

Tags: dockerfile, travis-ci

I'm trying to use the env variable set in travis ci in dockerfile. However when I echo the variable in dockerfile it is empty(not taking the value from the travis env variable). Could someone please help me with the same?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the [`ARG`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg) directive in your Dockerfile with the environment variable defined in Travis CI first.

```
FROM some.registry/image:latest

ARG USERNAME
ARG PASSWORD

...
```

Then, during Travis CI build, define the [`--build-arg`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables---build-arg) parameter with your variables as well.

```
docker build --build-arg USERNAME --build-arg PASSWORD .
```

The variables will be imported from the upstream properly this way.